# Use JavaScript to loop through all divs in a table

Tags: javascript, html

I have a HTML table that contain few div tags. I would like to loop on all the divs and change the align property to right. Does anyone have an example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

With jQuery

```
$(function(){
    $("table div").css("textAlign", "right");
});
```

Normal Javascript (fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JdTfk/ )

```
window.onload = function() {
    var tables = document.getElementsByTagName('table');

    for (var i = 0; i < tables.length; i++) {
        var divs = tables[i].getElementsByTagName("div");
        for (var j = 0; j < divs.length; j++) {
            divs[j].style.textAlign = "right";
        }
    }
}
```

Using CSS

```
table div
{
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: With the normal javascript example. where should i put it in order to invoke it after all the page is done loading. Using asp.net. thanks.

Comment: Is it really possible to call `getElementsByTagName` on a NodeList?

Comment: Updated my answer, because I was testing the normal Javascript, and this works, see the fiddle.

Comment: and if you do it only with css?

Comment: @MCSI yeah CSS would be the easiest way, add it to my answer.

Answer (score -4):

```
var divs = document.getElementsByTagName('div');
```

Comment: I'm guessing this was downvoted because it only tackles the first half of the OP's problem.  The second part is changing their `align` property to `right`.